# Data format from Matlab workspace

Tags: matlab

I have a data stored in the "Matlab workspace" in the following format:

```
data = 
Columns 1 through 12

-1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1
```

and I want to convert it into this simple form:

```
-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1
```

or even in this form also acceptable:

```
-1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1
```

the output data intended to be equal to the result of this command:

Str = ('-1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1');

originally I have a data in the following form "type=Double":

```
-1
-1
-1
-1
-1
-1
-1
-1
-1
```

I save this type double data into a variable using following command:

```
save data.txt data
```

Then I use the following code to import this data in my .mat file for further operation:

```
str = uiimport(); % import data
str = sprintf('%g', str); % or mat2str(str)
```

the resulting data type from this is although type char which is my required data type to get it process further. But it does not work. However if I directly put this data in my .mat file as str = ('-1 -1 -1 -1 - 1'); it works.

Comment: **num2str(value) and sprintf('%g',value)** does not work in my case.

Comment: What is wrong with `num2str`? Why does your input have 24 values, but the expected output only 12?

Comment: You're going to have to help us out here. You've ruled out two perfectly reasonable possibilities with no explanation whatsoever as to why they're wrong. Part of writing a good question is showing what you've tried and why those attempts do not produce the desired results.

Comment: @Daniel I just shortened the output to less number of 1s. So it has nothing to do with programming logic.

Comment: I just replaced my answer for your question. Probably the problem can be solved like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Cause

I had a hard time to figure out why you mention that `num2str` or `sprintf` don't work. I think you tried to directly pass the output of `uiimport` to `num2str` or `sprintf`. This gives you the error below. It would have been very helpful to include this in your question.

> Error using sprintf
> Function is not defined for 'struct' inputs.

#### Solution

The output of `uiimport` is a struct with all the resulting variables as fields. Therefore you need to address the `data`-field inside this struct like this: `S.data`.

*Here is the code:*

```
data = [-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1]'

save data.txt data              % store data
S = uiimport();                 % import data

str = sprintf('%g', S.data)     % without spaces
str = sprintf('%g ', S.data)    % with spaces
```

*This is the result:*

```
data =
    -1
    -1
    -1
    -1
    -1
    -1
    -1
    -1
    -1
    -1
    -1
    -1
str =
-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1
str =
-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
```

Comment: It works now. But I do not understand if **".data"** is a function or it just represent a link with data saved in variable **"data"**. so above the statement could possibly be generalize as **s = sprintf('%g', s.[variable Name);**]

Comment: @user3022649 `S`is a struct and `data` is a field of that struct. It gets accessed by `S.data`. Look [here](http://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/struct.html) for more information about structs and how to use them.